# Tableau after refresh of data- datatype gets changed everytime

Tags: tableau-api

I'm applying abs (absolute) function to a number that is coming in from the database. Once I apply it the report works fine. 
But, on next refresh- it goes back to showing no values. This time I'm required to change the abs function to round. Else it won't recognize.

Anyone else has faced the same issue?

So, what is happening with me is that, everytime I have a refresh to make- I am forced to manually change the type from abs to round and vice versa.

Comment: ABS() will only take numbers as argument. Don't know how it was working on ABS(string) in the first time, but it isn't supposed to work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's number in database- but wehnever I do refresh in tableau- it changes to an unknown type. The issue gets sorted only if I go with  Round or Abs function alternatively.

Comment: Seems more like a technical issue. What database are you using? Are you extracting data or using a live connection? Have you tried changing the data type in Tableau (right click on filed, Change Data Type)?